# Notification not sending to Firefox client(Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Node.JS on server side to send notification to 3 clients(browsers). Clients on *Microsoft Edge* and *Chrome* receive notifications, but *Firefox* do not (p.s. i'am testing on domain with https encryption)

**Client code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-app.js";
            import {
                getMessaging,
                getToken,
                onMessage,
            } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-messaging.js";

            const firebaseConfig = {
                /* <config> */
            };

            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

            const vapidKey = "vapid";
            window.messaging = getMessaging();
            window.messaging.onMessageHandler = console.log;
            getToken(window.messaging, { vapidKey }).then((token) => {
                const p = document.createElement("p");
                p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(token));
                document.querySelector("html").appendChild(p);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Server side code:**

```
const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("mycredentials.json");
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

firebase
    .messaging(app)
    .sendMulticast({
        tokens: [
            "<edge token>",
            "<chrome token>",
            "<firefox token>"
        ],
        data: {
            test: "Test",
        },
        webpush: {
            notification: {
                body: "Halo!",
                title: "notification_new_message",
            },
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    });
```

Unfortunately, I receive error:

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "success": true,
      "messageId": "<messageId>"
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "messageId": "<messageId>"
    },
    {
      "success": false,
      "error": {
        "code": "messaging/third-party-auth-error",
        "message": "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service"
      }
    }
  ],
  "successCount": 2,
  "failureCount": 1
}
```

I tried sending single request(`messages:send`) to Firefox Client, but it fails with the same error. Also, I tried to manually build and send raw [*Batch Request*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices), but result was the same.

How can I figure it out?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. FCM notifications have stopped working completely on Firefox. I contacted Firebase Support and they have reproduced the issue. They are looking into it.

Comment: @skynew, thx for your comment. I hope they will fix it

Comment: Exactly the same issue here.  Sending a test message using Curl using a Chrome token works as expected, but using a browser token created on Firefox fails with `AuthenticationError`.